# In HTML, can you use href to jump up one or more levels on a hard drive but not all the way to "file:///"?

Tags: html

Let's say the top-level folders on my hard drive are called 1, 2 and 3, and 1's folders are 1a, 1b, and 1c. Within 1a the folders are 1a1, 1a2, 1a3, and so on down the hierarchy. In

```
file:///1/1a/1a1/1a1a/1a1a1/1a1a1a/alpha.html
```

I can use href as follows:

```
href="beta.html"
```

refers to

```
file:///1/1a/1a1/1a1a/1a1a1/1a1a1a/beta.html
```

and

```
href="1a1a1a1/gamma.html"
```

refers to

```
file:///1/1a/1a1/1a1a/1a1a1/1a1a1a/1a1a1a1/gamma.html
```

If I were writing a file on the web, I could start the relative address with "/" to specify a filename beginning with the part after the domain name. But on my hard drive, if I want to refer to

```
file:///1/1a/1a1/1a1a/1a1a1/1a1a1b/delta.html
```

is there a shorter way than going all the way up to the top level and using

```
href= "/1/1a/1a1/1a1a/1a1a1/1a1a1b/delta.html"
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for "../", which lets you refer to the next level up.  Repeat to move multiple levels up.

Answer (score 0):

Specific to your question, you can use `../` to go up and `/` to go down name. So if you're going from `alpha.html` to `delta.html` you use the path:

```
../1a1a1b/delta.html
```

Which explained simply is

1. Goes up to `1a1a1`
2. Goes down to `1a1a1b`
3. Refers to `gamma.html`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Many thanks. This makes it much easier to build a website offline.

Comment: I build website builds all the time offline, and I learned this just a couple of months ago too. Happy Coding!